# xhr does not get invoked from js

Tags: javascript, cordova

i am using phonegap and trying to invoke a xhr POST on click of a button.

my flow goes to the method call but doesn't invoke the xhr code and i am failing to understand why.
The call looks like:

```
   function fetchTags(){
            console.log("Fetched url is:" + IMAGE_URL);
            //var url = "http://localhost:8080/echo";
            var url ="http://localhost:8080/echo";
            console.log("#1");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            console.log("#2");
            xhr.addEventListener("error", onError);function onError(evt) { console.log("An error occurred while transferring the file."); } 
            console.log("#3");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            console.log("#4");
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            console.log("#5");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                  var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  window.alert(response);
                }else{
                    window.alert(xhr.status);
                }
            };
            console.log("#5");


         //var msg = "{'message' : '" + IMAGE_URL + "'}"; 
         console.log("sending request");
         xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"message" : "my msg"}));

        }
```

Button code:

```
  <button class="button button-raised larger" type="button" onclick="fetchTags()">Vision</button>
```

The console prints:

```
Fetched url is:undefined
#1
#2
#3
```

To clarify i can see first console.log getting printed. but that's it. nothing happens after that.

Comment: I find it a bit ironic that you would call your function `fetchTags`, and then not use the `fetch` API.

Comment: Willing to bet your button is posting a  form when it is being clicked. Is the page refreshing? Cancel the button click or add `<button type="button" >`

Comment: but then it is printing the first console.log which i believe means it is going into the method and should finish rest of it

Comment: added button code

Comment: I would suggest to add an event handler if the request is failing. Something like `xhr.addEventListener("error", onError);function onError(evt) {
  console.log("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}`  and let us know the results.

Comment: updated the question with ur suggestion and output

Comment: If you're using firefox you may want to check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers

Comment: no firefox. code runs on ios and connected via phonegap desktop app. in short it's uses html5 +js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for everyone's benefit the issue was not the javascript but invoking from the phonegap using the localhost.

I was unders the assumption that phonegap will be able to access my api at localhost (not sure why had this stupid idea) but yes using the actual ip of the host machine made it work right away.